# Jquery - Select the <li> around <a href="specific-url">

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

This should be simple:

```
<li>
    <a href=""></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="specific-url"></a>
</li>
```

I want to select that `<li>` based on the `<a>` tag's attribute with specific url in the href. (Do not use `last-child`)

How can I?

Comment: What have you tried? jQuery's documentation is pretty extensive: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Have a look and try!

Answer (score 9):

As simple as:

```
$('a[href="specific-url"]').parent('li');
```

Comment: @Felix Kling: yep, and I used `parent()` intentionally, as an additional check :-)

Comment: Yeah I was more referring to gdoron's comment... fixed ;) Given the code, `.parent()` is the first that comes to mind anyway...

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
$('li:has(a[href="specific-url"])')
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf6Bp/)

Another way is:

```
$('li > a[href="specific-url"]').parent()
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf6Bp/1)

Comment: Oh, and there is even a selector for that. +1

Comment: Won't make use of `querySelectorAll` though ;)

Comment: I'm liking this one. Thanks for the demo!

Comment: I think the first is the cleanest. Second goes back and forth to go back again. Second works though too. Thanks @gdoron

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href='specific-url']").parent("li");
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the `a` then invoke `.parent()`.

**EDIT** Yikes, take 30 seconds to check your answer and *three* people get in there ahead of you...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="specifi_url"]').parent('li');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li a[href='specific-url']").parent();
```

Comment: Note that it can give you element which is not the `li`. it depends on the nesting.

Comment: This works for the HTML structure that is provided, but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li > a[href='specific_url']").parent()
```